# I have 2 websites (on different domains) that need to "talk" to each other. What solutions are there beside JSONP?

Tags: php, javascript, json, jsonp, web

I have 2 websites (on different domains) that need to "talk" to each other. Basically 1 website would be providing data and the other website would be reading data.

1. Since both websites are owned by me, is there anyway to overcome the  "same origin policy" ?
2. If not, other than JSONP what other solutions do I have ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: yes, look below

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Second: you can, look above

Comment: Why `*`? Shouldn't you be restricting access to just the domains involved?

Answer (score 1):

You can always make the cross site calls on the backend. i.e. setup a soap service on one and consume the soap service on the other domain.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is a way to override the same-origin policy as it comes from the user's JavaScript console built in to the browser.  However, you could post to a PHP cURL script.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: @genesis Good comment, but what is the browser support for that?  I heard that it isn't supported by all of them.  So which ones are?  Just curious.

Comment: I belive this is by most normal browsers (I still don't feel that IE is a browser)

Comment: @genesis I feel you on IE.  I don't like it either, but there are quite a number of people out there that still use it.